# What is the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: meaning

Can anybody tell me the difference between the following sentences ?

1. Her skirt **goes down** to her knees .
2. Her skirt **comes down** to her knees .

Thanks

Comment: Sentence 2 takes her knees as your point of view.

Comment: In general the bottom of something goes down whereas the top of it comes down. At least that's my take on it.

Comment: Without the context, this can't be answered.  They both mean the same thing, for one of two cases.  Either the length of her skirt reaches her knees, or her skirt as a unit drops to her knees.

Answer (score -1):

Sentence 1 indicates the length of her skirt that is up to her knees.
Sentence 2 implies that her skirt moves down to her knees. It may be very loose!

Comment: I don't think that's right. They can absolutely both have the first meaning.

Comment: Good. What would be the right form if her skirt is loose and reaches  to her knees?

Comment: If a skirt is falling down, you would say it's falling down (to her knees).